# Regex looping through a foreach to find a certain pattern

Tags: c#, xml

I'm using openXML and I'm trying to loop through an excel file to see if anything matches with a specific pattern. My Regex pattern is as fallows `@"(?<!\w)#\w+"`. This should return anything that starts with a "`#`". There are a number of defined names that begin with "`#`" such as `<definedName name="_KEY" hidden="1" localSheetId="3">#REF!</definedName>` in my excel workbook xml. However my count is returning zero when I try and find the defined name.

My code is as fallows

First I browse for the file and select the file. I've made sure that this works perfectly.

I then try and do a count and loop through each match and it's here where I have my issue. I assume I'm messing up my `foreach` loop and I really need some guidance.

```
    var spreadsheet = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filePath, false);
    var workbook = spreadsheet.WorkbookPart;
    var names = workbook.Workbook.DefinedNames;




    //result.InactiveNamedRangeCount = names.Where(n => n.InnerText.Contains(pattern)).Count();

    foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(names.ToString(), @"(?<!\w)#\w+"))
    {
            result.InactiveNamedRangeCount = names.Where(n => n.InnerText.Contains(match.ToString())).Count();

    }
```

Comment: You should never use regex to parse an xml or html.  Use the correct tools.  You can use the System.Xml library or System.Xml.Linq library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check what is returned by names.ToString(), you shouldn't run regex on it.

To get the number of DefinedNames matching your pattern, you can use:

```
names.Count(n => Regex.IsMatch(n.InnerText, @"(?<!\w)#\w+"));
```

Comment: Should I add this to my foreach loop or do I need to get rid of my foreach loop?

Comment: Hey, I edited the answer, it should be reflecting your needs now.